# Bootstrap Gallery Hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-gallery, mousehover

I have built a hover effect for my gallery. The gallery is within a Bootstrap Grid.
The hover itself works fine, but in some screen sizes the overlay goes over the gallery images.

Has anybody an idea or a solution or a hint for this problem?

Here an example:

[demo](http://codepen.io/herrgrab/pen/VjpajR?editors=1000)

---

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box .overbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(204, 36, 42, 0.75);
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.box:hover .overbox {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .title {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 131%;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 95px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .box .title {
        padding-top: 43px;
    }
}

.box .tagline {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.box_client {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.box_client:hover {
    background: rgb(235, 234, 233);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the overlay goes over the gallery images because you overlay has `width:100%;` and when the image is smaller than the width of its container the overlay goes over the gallery image because of the width of image

you have 2 options you can make the image `width:100%` or you can change the style of .box class and remove `width:100%;` and make its `display:inline-block;`

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    // width: 100%;          // remove this
    display:inline-block;    // add this
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap column is growing and shrinking while the image has the same fixed size. So `.responsive-image` is smaller than its parent `div`. There are a few solutions:

1) Remove the image in the html and have it as a background-image

```
.box {
   background: url(image-url) cover no-repeat;
}
```

2)  Make the image 100% width

```
.response-image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

3) Or as Ahmed Salama suggests, remove the `width: 100%` and add `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Your placeholder is smaller then the parent div element, which fits into the whole witdh of it's parent. Thats caused by the class img-responsive, that itself fits the the image to "max-width: 100%". You should use a bigger image or fit it to the size to your parent box, what is not recommended.

In this pen, i changed the placeholdersizes to 767px x 767px: http://codepen.io/pure180/details/OXpNxM/
HTML:

```
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/767x767" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/767x767" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/767x767" />
                        <div class="overbox">
                            <div class="title overtext">Client</div>
                            <div class="tagline overtext">Tag</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach: https://jsfiddle.net/5f285ask/3/

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box .overbox {
  background-color: rgba(204, 36, 42, 0.75);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.box:hover .overbox {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="overbox">
        overbox content
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this

```
.box {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
max-width: 300px;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 30px;}
```